# ipfs in docker seems unreliable

Tags: linux, docker, ipfs

I created a docker image that installs ipfs:

```
FROM python:slim

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y wget

RUN wget https://dist.ipfs.tech/kubo/v0.17.0/kubo_v0.17.0_linux-amd64.tar.gz
RUN tar -xvzf kubo_v0.17.0_linux-amd64.tar.gz
RUN cd kubo && bash install.sh
...
```

I start up a container opening all the ports that I think are needed for ipfs:
`docker run --rm -it -p 4001:4001 -p 5001:5001 -p 23384:23384 ...`

then inside the docker container I init ipfs and run the daemon using the ipfs cli:

```
ipfs init 
ipfs daemon
```

and I add and pin whole directories using the ipfs cli:

```
ipfs files cp /ipfs/$(ipfs add -r -Q <abspath>) /<name>
```

finally I can see the folders I've added:

```
# ipfs files ls
49plIeiN4whpqY7IJCj13jxLRa4=
DYXeJVfGb_aaYAZa2aFgAAbPIX0=
...
```

and the pins I've created:

```
# ipfs pin ls
QmUNxypYAurH8qBnFXUCnd6rjMUjiJtETx9hiYR2TbHTUy indirect
QmZcRZ2cXEUz3RQX887UVZ6y8U1KA4gtcsUuEFCcTa8vPH recursive
...
```

yet the pin CIDs are not only sometimes available on the ipfs network. most of the time I can't downloading them from outside the container, but sometimes I can. to test it I use a public gateway such as https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmacHp1rNyzyYCPLw5uDZCdcWCBB8w96pwTjcZVJgehgkh/

So. Is there somehting about how ipfs works that I'm missing? Does it take a long time to sync or is there an issue with my docker setup?

Is there an alternative solution? Maybe ipfs is overkill. I just wanted something easy to share files across the internet, and manageable through a cli, and I thought ipfs would be the best choice. Maybe I should turn to a torrent solution? Or something else?

Comment: You can test multiple things including if your node is reachable, and if your data is published to the DHT via https://ipfs-check.on.fleek.co.